# "def Type" declarations in groovy classes

Tags: groovy

Suddenly I've realized that I can write

```
class Person {
     def String name
}
```

My question is - what is the difference between code provided above and classic:

```
class Person {
   String name
}
```

Why first form even exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference.  Adding `def` to the beginning of a type definition does nothing.  However, it is allowed by the parser.

One way to check stuff like this, is to fire up the groovyConsole, and run the AST Browser (which for the script)

```
class Person {
     def String name
}
```

Shows:

```
public class Person extends java.lang.Object { 

    private java.lang.String name 

}
```

Comment: hm, it seems strange to me that this is allowed by parser, but thank you very much for teaching me to use the AST Browser in such cases.

Comment: @shabunc No worries, the AST browser is dead handy sometimes to see what is going on :-)  You probably know all this, but [this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+style+and+language+feature+guidelines+for+Java+developers) might have something of interest