# Why is using def and String at the same time when declare field in Gradle

Tags: string, groovy, gradle, function

```
 class GreetingPluginExtension {
    def String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
}
```

Why is used `def` and `String` at the same time, we have String type, why we use and **def** keyword?

Comment: You don't. `def String` is the same as `String`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368288/def-type-declarations-in-groovy-classes

Comment: But http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html
here you can find examples using with, it is not my code it is official Gradle documentation. I am wondering what is the purpose of this.

Comment: No particular purpose. `def message` or `String message` is more idiomatic Groovy.

Comment: That's a bug in the documentation

Comment: This is discussed in the Groovy style guide: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+style+and+language+feature+guidelines+for+Java+developers#GroovystyleandlanguagefeatureguidelinesforJavadevelopers-Defandtype

Answer (score 1):

The comments already answered this question a long time ago, but here's an updated link to the relevant section of the **Apache Groovy** *Style Guide:*

https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_def_and_type

It says:

> I often see developers using both **`def`** and a type.  But **`def`** is redundant here.  So make a choice, either use **`def`** or a type.

In general, my personal preference is for the clean, simple look of:

```
def message = "Hello"
```